# How is this kind of operation "a = x" or "a++" etc called?

Tags: c, compiler-construction

How do people that write compilers call it? I know that `int a, b, c;` is called an expression. But things like this: `int a = 2`? or `a++`, `a=c` etc I don't have any idea. And where do I find these terms? C standard or buy a book about compiler construction? I hope this is clear. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Isn't `int a, b, c;` a declaration?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
int a, b, c;
```

This is not an expression. This is a [declaration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Declaration_%28computer_programming%29).

```
int a = 2;
```

This is also a declaration. The `2` part is the [initializer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization_%28programming%29#Initializer).

```
a ++
```

This is a "[post-increment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Increment_and_decrement_operators)" [expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expression_%28computer_science%29). Note that outside of the C world this could be just a [statement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statement_%28computer_science%29).

```
a = c
```

This is an [assignment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_%28computer_programming%29) expression (which again, outside of C, this can be a statement).

---

The exact definition of these terms and categorization of each syntax ***for C*** can be found in the C standard (Chapter 6: Language), which you can find download/purchase information from [Where do I find the current C or C++ standard documents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81656/where-do-i-find-the-current-c-or-c-standard-documents).

Note that these are only true ***for C*** (and most of its derivatives, e.g. C++, Javascript, etc.). These concepts may not be meaningful in other languages (e.g. some language doesn't distinguish between statements and expressions).

Comment: You forgot to mention that `a++;` is also an lvalue. :)

Comment: @Hogan Are you sure `a++` is an lvalue ?

Comment: "post-increament" <-- typo. And `a = c;` is a statement; `a = c` is expression. I have a bit of doubt they can be called otherwise.

Comment: @cnicutar - it was when I wrote a compiler in grad school.  But, I just read that changed with newer versions of C... so I guess the answer is "depends".

Comment: And an operation that ends with a `,` independent if e.g, is assignment(a=0), pos-increment(a++), (a | x)  etc is there a name?

Comment: @nhahtdh: Thanks. Fixed the type. Since OP doesn't have the `;` I reordered it to say they are expressions in C.

Comment: @Jack: If you can read BNF form, it would help you understand why `a = c` is called an expression and `a = c;` is called a statement: http://www.cs.man.ac.uk/~pjj/bnf/c_syntax.bnf . About this `a = 0, a++, a | x`, it is called an expression, consists of other expressions, comma-separated.

Comment: @tuğrulbüyükışık: `new` is not part of C syntax, or at least in the link in my comment above.

Comment: @Jack: Not sure what do you mean.

Comment: @KennyTM: Strictly speaking, `2` is the initializer, not `= 2`.

Comment: @tuğrulbüyükışık: In C++, a "new" expression (C++11 §5.3.4).

Comment: I don't want to sound like an ass, but people who really write (new /fresh) compilers do not care what you call these _expressions_. It is all about set of inputs that can be parsed as a regular expression/transition graphs.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automata_theory
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_language_theory
http://people.cs.uchicago.edu/~blume/classes/aut2008/proglang/text/offline.pdf

Comment: @KennyTM, no in C prefix and postfix operators result in plain values, not in lvalues. You must be mixing it up with C++.

Comment: @Abhinav Regular expressions occur in the lexer, if at all. Parsing deals with CFLs. The terms 'regular expression' and 'transition graph' do not appear in either of your citations. And of course compiler writers care what they are called, as they have to name productions after them.